# Point Domain to Hostinger Server DNS Error

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

My Domain is on **Godaddy** and Hosting from **Hostinger**.  I linked that.

The problem is when I choose **DNS Server** 8.8.8.8 in **Wifi Network Ipv4**
The *site* does not load.  When I choose **Auto** the website works.
Can you please tell me what is the problem
Here is the link to website

[image: Dns]

Comment: Maybe 8.8.8.8. is firewalled somewhere.

Comment: have you changed nameservers with your registrar (godaddy) recently?

Comment: @Overmind Then My Why another website is running and not this one...

Comment: @JacobEvans Yes I changed nameservers..thats why it is running with auto DNS

Comment: @Shahid no sir, you switched dns recursive resolvers (your dns provider/client) I'm asking about your Nameservers, the servers you published with your registrar as to where your dns records are stored.

Comment: yes i changed recently

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; [Delete your DS records at Godaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/help/delete-a-ds-record-23867)

Looks like [Hostinger](https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/3667267-do-you-provide-dnssec) does not support external registrar's with DNSSEC, you'll need to disable DNSSEC at godaddy

If DNSSECis important to you, transfer registrars to Hostinger to enable DNSSEC

https://dns.google/query?name=ecoguardfilters.com&type=A&dnssec=true

```
{
  "Status": 2,
  "TC": false,
  "RD": true,
  "RA": true,
  "AD": false,
  "CD": false,
  "Question": [
    {
      "name": "ecoguardfilters.com.",
      "type": 1
    }
  ],
  "Comment": "DNSSEC validation failure. Check http://dnsviz.net/d/ecoguardfilters.com/dnssec/ and http://dnssec-debugger.verisignlabs.com/ecoguardfilters.com for errors"
}
```

More information at [DNSViz](http://dnsviz.net/d/ecoguardfilters.com/dnssec/)

[image]

Comment: Ok Sir... I will let you know after 48 hours.THanks

Comment: @Shahid updated answer